# Deleting CoreData entities before creating new entities is not working

Tags: ios, core-data

Basically I am trying to simply clear out a CoreData entity when a view loads before I call a web service to gather up-to-date data (since data will be updated from multiple platforms frequently). However, when I implement the delete entity code no data appears in my table view. I checked to see when the code is being fired in my view and it appears to be being called it the correct order.

```
2014-04-09 21:13:21.113 Karmo[28531:60b] Delete code being called
2014-04-09 21:13:21.122 Karmo[28531:60b] SetUpData being called
2014-04-09 21:13:21.123 Karmo[28531:60b] FetchData being called
```

If I comment out the delete code all the data is being displayed (but it gets duplicated because the old data is not deleted before grabbing new data :). It feels like I might be missing something small. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below I have included the viewDidLoad, delete, setUp, and fetch code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];

  //Delete entities from Core Data
  [self deleteEntityData];

  //Call the API and store the data to Core Data
  [self setUpData];}




- (void) deleteEntityData {

//Delete All Old Exlpore View Entities in Core Data

NSLog(@"Delete code being called");

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ExploreView" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[fetch setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *entities = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject * exploreView in entities) {
    [context deleteObject:exploreView];

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    };

}

}




- (void) setUpData {

//Create the string with the userID for the get request here
NSLog(@"SetUpData being called");

//Initialize AFHTTPRequestOperationManager with Dribbble API base URL
_operationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.karmo.com/explore/index"]];

[_operationManager GET:@"?user_id=XXXX" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

//Code to set up new Core Data Entity 

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {


    NSLog(@"Failed to fetch shots from Karmo API!");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Unable to Connect"
                                                   message:@"We were not able to connect to the karmo database. Some data may be out of date."
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                         otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

} ];

[self fetchData];}




- (void) fetchData {

NSLog(@"FetchData being called");

[exploreSortData removeAllObjects];
[exploreTableData removeAllObjects];
self.timeSortButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.voteSortButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Fetch the recipes from persistent data store
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ExploreView"];
exploreSortData = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

//Would probably need to call the category slelctions here. Use an if statment to capture so if non are seletced that all the categories are displayed

if ([selectedCategoriesFilter count] > 0 ) {

    for (int i = 0; i < [selectedCategoriesFilter count]; i++) {
        NSPredicate *newPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category ==[c] %@",[[selectedCategoriesFilter objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"categorySelected"]];
        [subPredicates addObject:newPredicate];

    }


    NSPredicate *combinedPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];

    NSArray *filterData = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    filterData = [exploreSortData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:combinedPredicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *voteDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"totalVotes" ascending:NO];

    NSMutableArray * descriptors = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:voteDescriptor, nil]mutableCopy];
    exploreTableData  = [[filterData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


} else {

    NSSortDescriptor *voteDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"totalVotes" ascending:NO];

    NSMutableArray * descriptors = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:voteDescriptor, nil]mutableCopy];
    exploreTableData  = [[exploreSortData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

}

Comment: Instead of Dribbble API implementing by yourself, you may use CocoaPods-ready Dribbble iOS SDK: https://github.com/agilie/dribbble-ios-sdk. It will save a lot of your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after your data is deleted or updated from the server. So you might be missing that call to reloadData.

Unrelated, but one other thing I noticed in your code is you're calling `[context save:&error]` within your for loop. You should move it out of the for loop to improve performance. A single [context save] will save all the deletes you make inside the for loop.

Comment: I added the `[self.tableView reloadData]` call after I delete the data but I am still getting the same result (blank tableView). Thank you for the tip on the save call. I will switch it outside the for loop.

Comment: Any other ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the difference - deleting CoreData entities, does NOT immediately release the NSManagedObjects associated with them!

Your code may retain those entities you just deleted somewhere (in an Array, or dictionary, or just as a member of some class) and so, your tableView still "sees" those objects.

Usually, to stay away from such problems you use an NSArrayController configured for "Entity" (vs. "Class") and bind your tableView to that array controller. The ArrayController is working against Entities, and not their object representations, and so it will stay in sync when you delete or add entities.